# The program show no errors, but it is not compiling. Can you please help me on what i need to do

Tags: c, compiler-errors

The program shows no errors, but it is not compiling. Can you please help me with what I need to do to solve this problem.

```
int main(void) {
    printf("\n*************************************************************\n");
    printf("\n*************************************************************\n");
    printf("\n******** Program find the solution to which car you *********\n"); 
    printf("\n******* could still earn if you received A's for the ********\n"); 
    printf("\n********* remainder of your undergraduate classes. **********\n");
    printf("\n*************************************************************\n");
    printf("\n*************************************************************\n");
    printf("\n  You will be asked to enter your current GPA with at most 3 \n");
    printf("\n  Decimal places and the number of credit hours that the GPA \n");
    printf("\n       Was based on, which should be a positive number.      \n");
    printf("\n  And the honors you qualify for will be displayed to screen.\n");
    printf("\n*************************************************************\n");
    printf("\n*************************************************************\n");

    printf("\nPlease enter your current GPA with at most 3 decimal places.\n");
    printf("\nFor example, for a GPA of 2.3333333333, enter 2.333\n");
    printf("\nThis GPA should fall between 0 and 4.0 --> ");
    scanf("%d, &numb1\n");
    printf("\n*************************************************************\n");

    printf("\nPlease enter the number of credit hours that this GPA was based");
    printf("\n on. This should be a positive integer\n");
    printf("\nFor example, for twelve credit hours, simple enter 12.\n");
    printf("\n-->");
    scanf("%d, &numb2");
    printf("***************************************************************\n");
}
```

Comment: How did you try to compile it? What compiler are you using? How did you determine that it doesn't compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a single argument to `scanf` because of where you put the double quote.

It should be: `scanf("%f", &numb1);` and `scanf("%d", &numb2);`

Note that `numb1` is `%f` since it's floating point and `numb2` is `%d` for integer.

Additionally, you never declared variables `numb1` or `numb2` so you also need: `float numb1; int numb2;` at the top of the function.

Comment: That doesn't match the prompt, which says to enter a number with up to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Good point, I didn't even read the `printf` contents. updated to read in floating point